# Thorntail with modules, server and web to Quarkus?

Tags: java, primefaces, quarkus

I have Java EE project with 10 modules, which have web and server side. I use primefaces, MySQL and other. It is real transform this project to Quarkus? Where there may be a problem?

Now I install myFaces, but web page do not show this elements(Primefaces and other). This procedure I found here on stackoveflow...some tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have a MyFaces+Quarkus sample application here: https://github.com/apache/myfaces/tree/2.3-next/extensions/quarkus/showcase
I would start to compare your app with the showcase, otherwise clone and it start from this.
PrimeFaces works fine with the MyFaces extension on Quarkus.
Other component libraries may not, we just added support for PrimeFaces as other component libaries are not active anymore.